# calculate encryption/decryption time of DNA encryption/decryption in java

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, time

I have implemented a DNA encryption and Decryption code in java in NetBeans IDE. I want to know if there is any way to calculate encryption and decryption time.

Comment: More details would help you get responses. Please explain what have you done with your code snippet and what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
encryption/decryptionMethodToTime();
long endTime = System.nanoTime();

long duration = (endTime - startTime);  //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but it should be noted that: 1) although the method is called `nanoTime`, the accuracy is typically in the order of milliseconds and 2) measuring the time of a single call is not a reliable way of profiling, because most likely external factors (other processes, etc.) have a higher impact on that time than your own algorithm.

Comment: than what is the method used for calculating the time in miliseconds